# Node.js: write after end error while writing on file decompressed gzip post data

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, gzip, zlib

I am writing here because I bumped into a Node.js problem which I am not able to solve by myself. Let's focus only on POST requests of the simple server I wrote.
My server has to accept only POST requests which contain gzip compressed data, then uncompress them and write the extracted content into a local file whose name resides inside the variable "path". 
I made almost everything of what I just explained, I also figured out how to uncompress gzip data, but I can't understand how to write the content into the file.

The POST request (performed on Debian) is always the following one:

```
curl -sS -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/gzip" --data-binary @<(echo "Uncompressed data" | gzip) http://192.168.1.66:8080/?path=test.txt
```

I tried many times in many different ways but despite it seems to me to be correct the execution always give me this output:

```
Adding Uncompressed data
 to buffer..
Entering ws on finish...
buffer: 'Uncompressed data
'
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:191:12)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:238:5)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Public\exercise2.js:54:14)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

My code is this one:

```
const fs   = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const url  = require('url');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const home = 'C:\\Users\\Public\\server_dir'

function handle_get(path,cb){
    fs.readdir(path,
           (err,files) => {
               if(err) cb(500,JSON.stringify({error : err.message, files: files||null})+'\n')
               else cb(200,JSON.stringify({error : null, files : files})+'\n')
           })
}

function handle_post(req,path,cb){
    function warn(err,event){
        if(err) console.warn(`Request ${event}, could not close ${path}`)
        else console.warn(`Request ${event}, ${path} closed succesfully`)
    }

    console.log("\n\nHeaders="+req.headers+"\n\n")
    var encoding  = req.headers['content-encoding']
    var cont_type = req.headers['content-type']

    if ((encoding == undefined || encoding.indexOf("gzip") <= 0) && cont_type.indexOf("gzip") <= 0)
      return cb(400, JSON.stringify({error : "Bad request: gzip encoding requested"})+'\n')

    fs.open(path,'w',0o644,
        (err,fd)=>
        {
            if(err) return cb(500,JSON.stringify({error : err.message})+'\n')
            const ws=fs.createWriteStream(null,{fd:fd})

            ws.on('finish',() => {
            console.log("Entering ws on finish...");
            cb(200, JSON.stringify({error : null, "written bytes":ws.bytesWritten})+'\n')
            })
            req.on('aborted',()=>fs.close(fd,err=>warn(err,'aborted')))
            req.on('error',(err)=>{
                fs.close(fd,err=>warn(err,'error'))
                cb(500,JSON.stringify({error : err.message, "written bytes":ws.bytesWritten})+'\n')
            })

            var buffer = [];
            var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
            gunzip.on('data',function(data) {
            var uncompressed = data.toString();
            console.log("Adding '"+uncompressed+"' to buffer..")
            buffer.push(uncompressed);
            //ws.write(uncompressed); // I've also tried this but it does not work
            }).on('end', function() {
                console.log("buffer: '"+buffer+"'");
                ws.write(buffer.join(""));
                ws.end();
            }).on('error',function(e) {
                console.log("error: "+e);
            })

            req.pipe(gunzip);
            req.pipe(ws);
        })
}

var s=http.createServer(
    (req,res) => {
        console.log("Request: "+req.method+" URL: "+req.url)

        function send(code,json_string){
            res.writeHead(code,{"Content-Type" : "application/json"})
            res.end(json_string)
        }

        if(req.method=='GET') handle_get(home+req.url,send)
        if(req.method=='POST') {
            var parsed_url=url.parse(req.url,true)
            var path=parsed_url.query.path
            console.log(parsed_url);
            if(!path)
                return send(400, JSON.stringify({error : 'Missing path'})+'\n')
            handle_post(req,home+path,send)
        }
  })

s.listen(8080);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you're piping from `req` to 2 separate write streams at the same time. This should also cause another problem because they're both flushing the stream at the same time. Meaning both targets would have incomplete versions of the request data. Also when youre using `fs.createWriteStream()` should should listen for the `'close'` event not the `'finish'` event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, locating the code related to ws inside the "end" event related to Gunzip.
Edited code:

```
var buffer = [];
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
gunzip.on('data',function(data) {
  var uncompressed = data.toString();
  console.log("Adding "+uncompressed+" to buffer..")
  buffer.push(uncompressed);
  //ws.write(uncompressed); // I've also tried this but it does not work
}).on('end', function() {
  const ws=fs.createWriteStream(null,{fd:fd})
    ws.on('close',() => {
    console.log("Entering ws on finish...");
    cb(200, JSON.stringify({error : null, "written bytes":ws.bytesWritten})+'\n')
  })
  console.log("buffer: '"+buffer+"'");
  ws.write(buffer.join(""));
  ws.end();
}).on('error',function(e) {
  console.log("error: "+e);
})

req.pipe(gunzip);
```